# Identify a plant and recommend how to save it

Tags: identification, plant-health, plant-recommendations

Can please somebody identify this plant? Are there any suggestions to save it? Its leaves are weak and getting yellowish.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to be *Dracaena fragrans ‘Massangeana’*. Other cultivars can look similar, but as this is the most widely available cultivar, I 'll go with with the most probable answer.

They are variegated so should have a yellow stripe, but your specimen looks like it desperately needs some more light. Word of warning - don't immediately stick it in the sunniest spot you can find as it might scorch. Move it progressively towards brighter light (indirect light from a window ideally).

It would be worth checking that it isn't sitting in water, as overwatering can lead to yellowing of leaves and is a more serious problem.

You could try adding a little general purpose houseplant fertiliser, following the manufacturer's instructions, to rule out any nutrient deficiency.

They are quite tough plants, so it should recover.